Elasticsearch Index Mappings getting modified after Snapshot Restore
I have a Hourly Snapshot which takes the backup of ES indices and the Data.
Now I am trying to restore the snapshot on a new cluster, if I do restore, restore is successfull.
But the restore is adding _meta and _doc fields to the mappings which is causing the structure to be different.
Index Mapping Before Snapshot
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties": {}
  }
}

Index Mapping After Restore:
{
  "mappings": {
    "enabled": false,
    "_meta": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {}
      }
    }
  }
}

This change is causing my code to break,
My Code looks for Properties under the mappings but after the restore it is under _doc which is different.
Source/Snapshot Cluster and Destination/Restore Cluster Elasticsearch versions is same.

I test it with Elasticsearch v8. The original index and restored indices mappings are identical.
Index Mapping After Restore: this looks like an old mapping structure of Elasticsearch prior to v7.
https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch
Please try to restore the data from Kibana DevTools, and share the API call and results step by step with me and let me check.

I took the snapshot on ES Version 8.13.2 and trying to restore it on the ES with version8.14.2. I did the restore it from the Kibana UI but not from the DEVTOOLS or using CURL. I tried with 8.13.2 on the New Cluster, But the Index mappings still  getting manipulated.

Can you share the index settings ?
